# javascript : Assign a method to another object without defining that method in second class body

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, class

I found this code in mozila developer site:[[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#global_context]](https://%5Bhttps://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#global_context%5D)

```
class Car {
  sayHi() {
    console.log('Hello from car');
  }
}
        
class Bird {
         
}
        
const car = new Car();
const bird = new Bird();

bird.sayHi = car.sayHi;
bird.sayHi(); //Why it works?!!!
```

How and why the last line works without defining method in second class or inherit that method from Car class?

Comment: Have you used your step-through debugger? If not, why not?

Comment: “*How the last line works without defining[…] sayHi method[…]?*” I mean, you *did* define it… maybe not in the traditional sense or in a way that is considered common practice, but you did set a reference to the method as part of your `bird` variable

Comment: You've just discovered why we say that Javascript is prototype-oriented, not object-oriented :).

Comment: thus it means this type of style allows the creation of an object without first defining its class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's walk through what exactly happens here.

1. You define the class for Car.  That creates a constructor named `Car` and creates a prototype for that class.
2. You define the `sayHi()` method in the class definition.  That adds the `sayHi` method to the Car prototype.
3. You define the class for Bird.  That creates a constructor named `Bird` and creates a prototype for that class.
4. You create an instance of each class.  That creates an object, assigns the corresponding prototype and runs the constructor (if there is one).
5. You execute `bird.sayHi = car.sayHi;`.  That has two parts.  First, it reads `car.sayHi`.  Since there is no own property named `sayHi` on the `car` object, the interpreter checks the prototype chain for that object and finds the `sayHi` method on the prototype.  Then, it takes that method that it found and assigns it to the `bird` object as an own property (a property directly on the `bird` object.  Remember, a method is JUST a function that is stored on an object.  You can grab that function off the object and use it like any other function (it may or may not work properly when removed from its original context - that depends upon what it does).
6. Then, you execute `bird.sayHi()`.  That causes the interpreter to look on the `bird` object for an own property named `sayHi` and it finds the one that you just assigned.  It grabs that method and executes it and you get your output in the console.

Comment: Thanks. thus i understood that object own properties and prototype properties are two different context... and we can get all of own properties with `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`

Answer (score 1):

[Functions are first class objects.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/First-class_Function#:%7E:text=A%20programming%20language%20is%20said,a%20value%20to%20a%20variable.)

Internally, `car` is an empty object with a prototype that has its `sayHi` property defined.

Then, with `bird.sayHi = car.sayHi`, you are setting the `bird.sayHi` property.